# Codeigniter Write_file Question

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing to a txt file to back up certain posts.  Here is my simple code

```
$this->path = APPPATH . "post_backups/";
    $string = $this->input->post('post');
    $post_title = $this->input->post('post_title');
    $this->file = $this->path . $post_title."txt"; 
    write_file($this->file, $string);
    $this->index();
```

Every thing works fine except this

```
$this->file = $this->path . $post_title."txt";
```

I am trying to name my file with the title of the post IE: title.txt.

What I am getting it s this "titletxt".  How should the $post_title . "txt" be written to provide txt as an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->file = $this->path . $post_title.".txt";
```

Not quoted, `.` is used to concatenate strings, so just add a period to your string. Inside the quotes it's treated as a character literal.

Comment: Perfect!  the simplest things are always the hardest to see.  Thank you very much